# Pulling Bond CUSIPs via Bloomberg API

Tags: python, excel-2007, bloomberg

I'm trying to pull all the active German bond cusips from bloomberg using blpapi ( excel or python either ). Does anyone know how to do it? I would appreciate your help. ( p.s. I can search "DBR Govt" in bbg and export to csv, this manual labor is not what I'm looking for )

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, depending on what you're trying to do. The simplist in excel is to use BChain.

```
BChain("3413Z GR Equity,"BONDS","H").
```

You can also specify bond types with overrides like this, so you could include certain maturities, etc.

```
=BChain("3413Z GR Equity","BONDS","CPN > 2")
```

That will give you the bloomberg corp identifiers in a column, like AN089876 Corp, which you can then use to get whatever you need, cusip, coupon, maturity, price, etc.